# Writing a Number Guessing program in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

Here is the question im trying to address and here is what I have. I am not sure what i've done wrong but it will not run in WebStorm:

```js
alert("This is question 1");

var rndmNum = Math.rndmNum();
rndmNum = rndmNum * 100 + 1;
var i = 0;
do {
  var rndmNum = prompt;

  function guessNum(guess) {
    if (guess < rndmNum);
  }
  alert("Your guess is too low");
} else if (guess > rndmNum) {
  alert("Your guess is too high");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Question 1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Question 1</h1>
  <p>
    This is a page used to run/execute some JavaScript.
  </p>
  <p>
    Next <a href="question2.html">question</a>.
  </p>
  <p>
    Return <a href="index.html">home</a>.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

does anyone see any problems in what I have done or have any recommendations? Feedback is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error:

```
function guessNum(guess)  {
    if (guess<rndmNum);
}
    alert ("Your guess is too low");
}
else if (guess>rndmNum)  {
    alert("Your guess is too high");
}
```

Should be:

```
function guessNum(guess)  {
    if (guess<rndmNum) {
        alert ("Your guess is too low");
    }
    else if (guess>rndmNum)  {
        alert("Your guess is too high");
    }
}
```

You have an else if when your if statement was separated by an alert.

Also

1. Your brackets {} do not properly close.
2. The do is not syntactically correct or needed.
3. Math.rndmNum() is not a real method, think you want Math.random()

Answer (score 0):

I only briefly looked at it.  I don't really approve of giving answers for homework questions, but I will pose a question for you.

What if someone puts in something besides a number?  You check if the answer is lower or higher, but you never make sure that it's actually a number.

You might want to consider either validating that the answer being checked is a number before checking it, or checking only for the answer you're looking for.

Also, `var i = 0`.  I'll assume that you're going to use that later in your code, but `i` is pretty much a universal JavaScript variable.

What you're doing there is setting the global variable `i` to = 0, and most likely you're going to change that somewhere else in your code.  Then you might run a `for` loop that rewrites `i`, or you might have an extension that rewrites it.

Consider naming your variables more uniquely, or keep the scope of the variables that aren't unique to functions or loops.

Answer (score 0):

first of all. if you want to generate random number use:
`Math.random()` because `Math.rndmNum` is undefined

prompt is function and to use it you should write:

`var rndmNum = prompt('geuss a number');`

to convert random number from float to integer:

`rndmNum = Math.floor(rndmNum * 100 +1);`

and do-while loop should be:

```
do  {
    var rndmNum = prompt('geuss a number');;
    function guessNum(guess)  {
        if (guess<rndmNum){
            alert ("Your guess is too low");
        }else if (guess>rndmNum)  {
            alert("Your guess is too high");
       }
    }
   i++;
}while(i<10) // number of guesses
```